# Merge cell and copy equation in google scripts in google sheets

Tags: scripting

I am looking to make a script that will merge cells to like the blue ones are based on the ones in the green when the only constant is the cell that says credits. I am hoping for an option that make it variable but I can live with it doing the the same amount of cells each time just as long as it happens only when the associates cells.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng0nb.png)

I am also looking to have a script fill the column that the green options are with copies of that equation keeping the relatively of the equation and places them in when the column that the blue cell is in has the cell filled

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PLJm.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand your question and your 2 images. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal? And, what language do you want to achieve your goal using?

Comment: i want to create a script that will run in a spreadsheet and update it to fit the format of the cells in the pictures by merging the cells like i have the akstilleto merged based on what the where credits are. it is already done in the pictures manually but i have set up a master document that can update every copy that is made from this. i also want to automatically copy the equations onto rows that have a resource listed but only if there is a resource listed. i have no scripted made because nothing really explains what i am looking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @tanaike [hopefully this helps you understand what i am asking](https://youtu.be/82iRtdfnwik)